# How to get nodes or traverse by labels in Neo2.x

Tags: neo4j, java

For example, I have several friends who have labels such as teachers , doctors , singers. How can I get all my teacher friends? I can reach my goal by Cypher ,but I want more efficient ways like Java-api functions.

I mean I want to get all the nodes from the node “I”, so the following way doesn't work for me

```
GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb).getAllNodesWithLabel(DynamicLabel.label('teacher'));
```

Thx for anybody can give me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Node me = graphDb.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(DynamicLabel.label("Person"), "name", "Me")
for(Relationship rel : me.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("KNOWS")) {
  System.out.println("My teacher friend: " + rel.getEndeNode());
}
```

Which is the equivalent of this Cypher

```
MATCH (me:Person {name:"Me"})-[:KNOWS]->(teacher) RETURN teacher
```

Also check out the manual section [Using Neo4j embedded in Java applications](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.1/tutorials-java-embedded.html)

Comment: DynamicRelationshipType.withName("Teacher") is that mean "Teacher"is the relationship's name? In my Db, all my friends just have one relationship with me MyRelTypes.KNOWS.

Comment: Yes. "Teacher" is the relationship type (I violated the convention to uppercase those, let me fix that). In your case you'd just put in your MyRelTypes.KNOWS instead.

Comment: But I still can't get my teacher friends then...as I know different types of friends...

Comment: The query places no restrictions on the end node. The query restricts "me" to have a Person label, the relationship type to be KNOWS, but the node at the other end of the relationship can be anything, it'd be restricted to nodes labeled Teacher if it would read ...[:KNOWS]->(teacher:Teacher).

Comment: I know that can be implemented by cypher...I want Java-api functions...thx anyway...

Comment: I used the Cypher query to explain, but the same applies to the Java code - it does exactly the same. It asks for KNOWS relationship outgoing from the 'me' node. The nodes returned from 'rel.getEndNode()' can also be anything, just like in the Cypher query.

Comment: How can I give a limit to the nodes I get from 'rel.getEndNode()'. The  function hasLabes() can do a favor...But if I have 1000 friends, it'll  take too much time to make a judgement...

Comment: Depends on what you want to limit. If your data set is small you could just iterate over end nodes and pick the ones you like. If you have more data and want to do fancier stuff you could look into traversal descriptions, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.1/tutorial-traversal.html